# Equations of State

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, temperature, dimensional-analysis

I'm having trouble coming to any meaningful answers in this question,

[image]

It seems to me like all of the variables given can be put generally in terms of T. I can't seem to figure out any kind of equation of state that seems to give a meaningful answer. Can anyone get anything out of this question? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The general equation for dU as a function of dT and dV is:

$$dU=C_vdT-\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right]dV$$If U is a function only of T, then the term in brackets is zero.  This should help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116530/discussion-on-answer-by-chet-miller-equations-of-state).